# Update front after ajax request in for function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a project where I sent an array to a foreach in PHP and it worked, the question is that it took a long time and it showed timeout, I try to do that for from js and ajax so that it sends the request to PHP and returns, update the value of the registry and return to PHP, this to avoid this timeout error, but when doing the synchronous for, the PHP function works ok and return data, but does not update the front with the information.

I have tried with success and with .done and it doesn't work as I want.

```
      for(var i = 0 ;i < ids.length; i++){
        console.log(i+' '+ids[i]);
        var parametros = {'val1' : ids[i]}
        $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: "{{path('enviar_fac')}}",
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
          success: function(data){
              alert("success: "+i);
              document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById("resultados").innerHTML = "id: "+i+" data: "+data;
          }
        });
      }
```

thanks

Comment: This is not good to call ajax in for. Maybe you should to find out another method to do it. If I were you I will send ids as the request.

Comment: Just because it send to the Server, the response took too long. Never use synchronous AJAX. It's a bad practice. Also, you are overwriting the same Element property values.

Comment: Can you add some of your HTML code?